# How many ways are there to do c++ in win32

Tags: c++, winapi

So, with win32 assembly, there used to be TASM, MASM and I think another 'brand' of assembly language.  Does that kind of "branding" appear in the win32 C++ world as well?

I notice there's an MS visual C++... an IDE...  there's also Dev-C++, another IDE...  are each of those IDEs using different compilers which have different expectations of your source code, or will projects cross compile between those two IDEs.

**Edit:**  What about when people use Cygwin?  I at first wasn't sure if binaries compiled in cygwin would only run within the cygwin environment, but now I see they're native windows binaries that are created. So people must use cygwin for dependency handling comfortability?  I noticed it's a major pain, for instance, installing libCurl onto a windows machine and setting it up for use with dev-C++, and I notice a quick look at http://cygwin.com/packages/ shows libcurl as an available package.

Comment: Can you rephrase the question may be with examples? As it stands its not making much sense.

Comment: The other guy pretty much hit the nail on the head, he even listed off "build systems" which was something I was in the dark about. Do you not know what TASM and MASM means? They're different syntaxes of Assembly language, whereas in the C++ world, it seems there are standard versions where C++ matures and gains access to more compiler features.  I think the crucial takeaway is that C++ is done in conformance to a specific version of C++, and also, different "build systems" are used to invoke particular compilers to build .EXEs.  Hope that helps their down voting faces, but w/e, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does that kind of "branding" appear in the win32 C++ world as well?

1. There are several different compilers (microsoft compiler, borland compiler, open watcom compiler, mingw (gcc windows port), llvm (I think it shold be possible to get it working), etc).
2. There are several different C++ standards (C++98, C++03, C++11). Different compilers(compiler version) migh support different language versions to a certain degereee.
3. There are several different build systems (MSBuild, nmake, cmake, qmake, scons, jam, jom, ant).

> What about when people use Cygwin?

You should seriously check cygwin documentation. This one is too simple.

> or will projects cross compile between those two IDEs

Different IDE can use same compiler. You don't "cross compile to different IDE". IDE merely acts like an interface between user and build system. Instead of using IDEs to BUILD projects, it makes sense to get acquinted with other build systems, and use IDE only as text editor.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using the "mainstream" Microsoft tools such as the C++ in Visual Studio.  I have used  other tools before such as MinGW and they "work" for simple apps such as CLI tools.

The issue is you won't get very far programming in windows before you need to use COM and all it's related wrappers and tools (ex. ATL wizards etc.)  Without a deeply integrated tool such as Visual Studio COM gets very cumbersome (even more than it already is)